# Mac OS X Snow Leopard hangs after login

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

After restoring from backup following filesystem corruption my user account hangs after login (After entering my password the login window disappears and all I get is the background and a mouse pointer, no spinning wheel of death etc ..) I can login as a different user and then logout and login as my main account (sometimes!) but this is not consistant.

I can login with safemode ok and have tried deleting /System/Caches, ~/Library/Caches and removing all my ~/Library/Preferences which worked once but not again.

Does anyone have an any idea which logs I can look in, if any, to see whats happening after login or any other tips?

I'm using 10.6.2.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it works in safe mode, you should check the things that get [disabled in safe mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564).  Since this problem only occurs in the login session, the prime suspects are probably login items (check in System Preferences -> Accounts -> your account -> Login Items tab), LaunchAgents (check both /Library/LaunchAgents at the root of the boot drive, and ~/Library/LaunchAgents in your home folder; note that items in /System/Library/LaunchAgents are not disabled in safe mode, so aren't suspects), and fonts (again, check both /Library/Fonts and ~/Library/Fonts).  Experiment with disabling the various items to narrow down which one's causing the problem.

Comment: If the problem is specific to the login items, one could just login with Shift held down (http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20716) instead of doing a whole safe boot. If it still fails, then try a safe boot. If it works, then one only has to check the login items instead of all the stuff a full safe boot disables.

Answer (score 2):

I had that same problem. It got resolved when I entered the account in Safe Mode, and uninstalled Little Snitch. I reinstalled it later, when I could enter the account without any further problems.

Comment: Little snitch was infact the problem!. I'm accepting the answer above though as it may be more helpful to solving similar probs.